# getting error when uploading image (php/codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, upload

My problem is about making a directory in linux. My website has a back-end in which i can upload images for the site and it automatically creates folders according to YEAR and Month in which images were uploaded.

But from changing the web host platform windows to linux i got errors, i am able to upload images successfully but unable to see it when it uploads.

If i upload a image with name `pdf.png` from my backend (admin panel) then it shows nothing and i see the image was uploaded in the form of `2012\09\pdf.png` in my upload folder of website. but i want this uploaded file in my `/2012/09/` folder. the folder was created automatically according to year and month.

Please find the [Screen Shot of error and source code (ZIP)](http://www.mediafire.com/?bpnh18a7pbzn83h) for my php program, if you find something wrong please help me to solve it, thanks!

```
    function upload()
    {
    $a = $this->_make_dir();       
    if(move_uploaded_file($a["tmpname"], $a["target"]))
    {
        echo 'success';
        $this->art_media->create(array("media_filename"=>$a["file"],
            "media_date"=>time(),
            "media_title"=>$a["file"],
            "media_description"=>"",
            "media_filelink"=>date("Y")."/".date("m")."/",
            "media_isimage"=>false,
            "media_type"=>$a["filetype"]
            ));

    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
function _make_dir()
{
    $target1 = FCPATH.$this->config->item("articles_media").date("Y");
    $target = $target1."\\".date("m");

    $uploadfile = $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
    if(!is_dir($target1))
    {
        mkdir($target1);
        mkdir($target);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_dir($target))
        {
            mkdir($target);
        }
    }        
    if(is_file($target."\\".$uploadfile)==true)
    {
        echo 'duplicate';
        exit();
         //$uploadfile = $uploadfile."_".$n;
    }
    return array("filetype"=>$type,"file"=>$uploadfile,"targetpath"=>$target."\\","target"=>$target."\\".$uploadfile,"tmpname"=>$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked folder permission (does the 'other' user have write permission)? E.g parent_folder permissions = 777

Comment: can you check my attachment url (mediafire).

Comment: It would be a good idea to help us help you. Just throwing a (nested!) ZIP file with lots of code into StackOverflow is not helpful at all. At least try to isolate the relevant code and post it here.

Comment: i am unable to provide source code in the comment box :( bcz of limitation.

Comment: @Rohan - try editing your question. Press Ctrl+K to insert a code block...

Comment: @Rohan You can edit your question anytime.

Comment: ok, please let me know if this question doesn't help you to identity my problem so i edit it again. thanks for the responses, just waiting for the help :)

Comment: have you tried putting some code in to test the mkdir() function calls?, it will return false on failure

Comment: also, why not use CI upload class? This will give you a full relevant error message if the upload fails, so then you know the issue is the creating of directories.

Comment: @Rooneyl Is there any problem in my source code.

Comment: @Rohan it seems OK but to be honest I haven't got the time to test it thoroughly. Just trying to help you find out what is wrong. Assuming the code is fine (it should as you said it was working before) have you tried to test the folder creation/permissions?

Comment: @Rooneyl it means there is no relationship between windows and linux to create a directory with php program. Because site was working fine in IIS server, i just got this problem in linux platform.

Comment: Tried replacing all the double backslashes \\ with single forward slashes `/`? Directories traversing works differently on Windows and Linux, this could be _a_ problem, even though I'm not sure I understand what the _actual_ problem is.

Comment: @froddd that's why i attach the source code in zip file along with a screen shot, but everyone are looking for a quick view.

Comment: I've just had a look at the file you've attached. The code is exactly the same as what you've posted here. People have been making suggestions already. Have you tried any of them? If the answer is no, go back to your code, try the suggestions. If they don't work, come back here and tell us what error you're getting then.

Comment: @froddd superb sir, the problem was solved! its just because of / forward slash, i replaced \\ with / and its work fine, thanks! Thank you everyone ...

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux work differently for traversing directories: Windows uses backslashes while Linux uses forward slashes.

You should replace all the escaped backslashes with forward slashes. For instance, this:

```
$target = $target1."\\".date("m");
```

should become:

```
$target = $target1."/".date("m");
```